# How do i properly set up local host such that it displays p5.js canvases

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I was looking to learn webgl so I started a simple project and was having trouble setting up a local host that would work.
so the local host looks like this:

[image: Reference Image]

but when I just open my index.html file from the file explore I get what I am supposed  to:

[image: Reference Image]

I am using the p5.js, although I am not sure if that would mess anything up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: did you write a leading slash in the src attribute when importing p5.js?

When running a server, you should be careful when embedding and/or importing resources; probably you imported p5.js like this:

```
<script src="directory/p5.js"></script>
```

Or similar, but correct when running a server would be:

```
<script src="/directory/p5.js"></script>
```

Because accesses like this need a leading slash to tell the server where to find the resource, in this case, your p5.js file at the root directory of the server.

I hope I could help you!